# What is the best way to architect multi-region Cluster Mode Enabled Elasticache setup using Redisson for a Java app?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, architecture, amazon-elasticache, redisson

I am trying to setup multi region Cluster mode enabled Elasticache cluster setup for a Java app that uses redisson library to connect.

I have explored below options which seems to be not viablefor our use-case
Redisson has MultiClusterMode option but it is available only for PRO customers
Global Datastore from AWS but supported node types are above R6(costly instances)

Is there a possibility to use CircuitBreaker to failover to other region if one-region goes down during runtime?

Is it possible to register two clustermode enabled clusters which has two master nodes at the same time?

Getting below error when I tried

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative names matching IP address **** found